# MS Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel file: [payroll.xlsx](http://www.2shared.com/file/5eeVIozO/payroll.html)

I need to do the following, but I'm not sure how:

> Create a pivot table that computes per
>   employee how many times s/he checked
>   in and her/his average amount of time
>   worked. There should be a block of
>   rows in the table for each employee
>   for whom you have payroll data, and
>   each block should have separate
>   entries for the number of shifts
>   worked and the average time worked by
>   that employee.

I'm not sure if the Excel file is just wrong or if I'm not doing it correctly.  It's supposed to have: Employee Names (not Employee ID).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a column 'Employee Name' to the source table in column G.  Do this with the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,EmployeeData!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Refresh your pivot table and use 'Employee Name' instead of 'Employee ID'.